# CoffeeScript idiom for Array.reduce with default value

Tags: coffeescript

In CoffeeScript sometimes I need to call [`Array.reduce(...)` with a default value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce); however, the unfortunate ordering of the arguments means the initial/default value goes after the reduce function itself, which means I've got to use a lot of parens, which seems much uglier than CoffeeScript wants to be.

For example:

```coffeescript
items = [ (id:'id1', name:'Foo'), (id:'id2', name:'Bar') ] # ...
itemsById = items.reduce(((memo, item) -> # <-- Too many parens!
  memo[item.id] = item
  memo), {}) # Ugly!
```

Is there a more idiomatic way to do this in CS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've run in to this myself with other functions. In cases where its really made a mess of things (or it just really bothers me), I might declare the function elsewhere (perhaps above that line), and then pass the function as a parameter, something like so:

```
reduce_callback = (memo, item) ->
    memo[item.id] = item
    memo

itemsById = items.reduce reduce_callback, {}
```

Unfortunately, you expand a whole lot vertically, which may or may not be desirable. This is merely a general suggestion.

Comment: I do the same sort of thing, especially when chaining functions with callbacks (e.g. when building an Underscore pipeline or even chaining a bunch of Enumerable methods in Ruby).

Answer (score 6):

This works:

```
itemsById = items.reduce (memo, item) ->
  memo[item.id] = item
  memo
, {}
```

Comment: +1 this is a good alternative but the leading `, {}` on the final line requires visual backtracking to the `itemsById` line then a scan to the end of that line; ultimately this doesn't seem any more clear to me than my example =\

Answer (score 0):

```coffee
items = [ {id:'id1', name:'Foo'}, {id:'id2', name:'Bar'} ]
itemsById = {}
itemsById[item.id] = item for item in items
```

Clean and readable.