# reduce() in CoffeeScript - how do I pass a default value?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, ecmascript-6, reduce

So I've been toying around with CoffeeScript a bit recently. So far the transition from JS has been rather smooth, but now I've finally run into a problem I really can't figure out.

I've got this piece of ES6:

```
function upcaseOddIndexes (arr, cha, ind) {
  if (ind % 2 === 0) {
     arr.push(cha.toUpperCase());
  } else {
     arr.push(cha);
  }
  return arr;
}

var string = "stringthing";
var upcasedString = string.split("")
                    .reduce((arr, cha, ind) => upcaseOddIndexes (arr, cha, ind), [])
                    .join("");

console.log(upcasedArray);
```

which does its job (returning a new string with the letters at odd indexes uppercased) just fine. The `upcaseOddIndexes` function is no problem either. But  how do I pass the empty array as the `initialValue` to `reduce()`?

My best guess was

```
.reduce(arr, cha, ind -> upcaseOddIndexes arr, cha, ind) []
```

which gives me

```
.reduce(arr, cha, ind(function() {
  return upcaseOddIndexes(arr, cha, ind);
 }))([])
```

and that's going nowhere, since `arr is not defined`.

I've tried adding more parens, commas and whatnot, but I always meet with `unexpected ,` or something similar.

I've already had a good rummage around Google, but haven't found an answer so far. There's [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22028924/coffeescript-idiom-for-array-reduce-with-default-value) on the topic, but it didn't really help.

Thanks a lot in advance =)

Comment: Going from ES6 to CS seems like a step backwards.

Comment: @FelixKling CS compiles to ES6 so that doesnt make a lot of sense

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reduce `(arr, cha, ind) => upcaseOddIndexes (arr, cha, ind)` to `upcaseOddIndexes`:

```
string = "stringthing"
upcasedString = string
.split ""
.reduce upcaseOddIndexes, []
.join ""
```

That is converted to

```
var string, upcasedString;

string = "stringthing";

upcasedString = string.split("").reduce(upcaseOddIndexes, []).join("");
```

or without reduction:

```
string = "stringthing"
upcasedString = string
.split ""
.reduce (arr, cha, ind) ->
  upcaseOddIndexes arr, cha, ind
, []
.join ""
```

That is converted to

```
var string, upcasedString;

string = "stringthing";

upcasedString = string.split("").reduce(function(arr, cha, ind) {
  return upcaseOddIndexes(arr, cha, ind);
}, []).join("");
```

Comment: *You can reduce...*
Heh. Punny. On a serious note, this is a great response--it answers the question directly but also offers a further simplified solution that addresses what the author is ultimately trying to accomplish. Well answered.

Comment: You will do great things in life. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the comma at the end of the call to `reduce`:

```
.reduce ((arr, cha, ind) ->
  upcaseOddIndexes arr, cha, ind
), []
```

You'll find a Javascript to Coffeescript converter [here](http://js2.coffee/)

Comment: But the `[]` has to be passed to the `reduce` function.

Comment: @FelixKling And for anyone else reaching here, it will end inside the reduce function once transpiled into javascript.